# Show HTML instead of browser alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've got the following script for a game:

```
 $(function() {
     $("#sortable").sortable({
         opacity: 0.6,
         cursor: 'move',
         update: function() {
             var winningString = "g01,g02,g03,g04,g05,g06,g07,g08,g09,g010,g011,g012,g013,g014,g015,g016";
             var currentString = '';
             $('#sortable li').each(function() {
                 var imageId = $(this).attr("id");
                 currentString += imageId.replace("recordArr_", "") + ",";
             });
             currentString = currentString.substr(0, (currentString.length) - 1);
             if (currentString == winningString) {
                 alert("Congratulations! You have completed the challenge.");
             }
             console.log(currentString);
         }
     });
 });
```

Now what I'd like to do is **to show HTML message instead of the browser alert**. But I can't figure how to change it with the alert part of the script, at least without getting an error.

... adding `$( "#message2" ).dialog();` gave **TypeError...dialog is not a function**

**The HTML message:**

```
<div id="message2" title="">
  <p>Congratulations! You have completed the challenge.</p>
</div>
```

Have the following scripts in my `<head>`:

- jquery.ui.core.js
- jquery.ui.widget.js
- jquery.ui.mouse.js
- jquery.ui.sortable.js

Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should include jquery ui along with jquery. Dialog is function of jquery ui

http://jqueryui.com/

Comment: Yes, downloaded the latest stable install and added the jquery-ui.css, jquery.js and jquery-ui.js  in the <head> section and problem is solved. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:
    alert("Congratulations! You have completed the challenge.");

```
$( "#message2" ).html('  <div class="sulgeja"><a href="#" class="close">Sulge</a></div>
<p>Congratulations! You have completed the challenge.</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery-UI dialog isn't a part of the four jquery.ui scripts you listed. I would either just download the complete jQuery-ui library or create a custom version using their [Download Builder](http://jqueryui.com/download/)